# Postgresql with node (column "" does not exists -> syntax error at or near ",")

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a small problem regarding inserting into PostgreSQL. A problem that I have not faced before, since I have similar inserts that work just fine. I'm receiving a req.body from a post request from where I insert everything into the correct tables in PostgreSQL, this is one of the .then statements inside the db.task.

When my code arrives at this part I get the error "column "name" does not exist" if the firstname inside the req.body.org is "name".

If I send an empty string, I get the error "syntax error at or near ",". I have used the same practice when handling similar post requests without getting any errors. I also tried console logging the db.one task instead of inserting it, and it returns all the correct answers corresponding to the "org" array object. So it returns everything correct, but for some reason I keep getting an error. I have trying to debug this for days, but to no avail. I hope someone here can help me out.

Thanks in advance guys! Br, Victor

```
"org": [
    {
        "firtsname": "name",
        "lastname": "testA",
        "orcid": "testB",
        "rooli": "testC",
    }
],




.then((id: any) => {
return db.one("INSERT INTO org (id, firstname, lastname, persid, role)" + 
 "values (" + JSON.parse(id.id) + ", " + req.body.org.map((e: any) => e.firstname) + 
 ", " + req.body.org.map((s: any) => s.lastname) + ", " + req.body.org.map((x: any) 
 => x.persid) + ", " + req.body.org.map((y: any) => y.role) + ") RETURNING id");
```

})

Comment: what's the postgresql server version you are using?

Comment: 9.2.24 Sorry I should've specified this in the question

Comment: Why aren't you using placeholders? Pasting strings together to build an INSERT is madness and leaves you wide open to all sorts of problems. Also, won't `req.body.org.map(...)` give you an array? Wouldn't it be better to grab the org you want (`let org = req.body.org[0];`) and then work with that?

Answer (score 0):

there should be a space before "values"

```
persid, role)" + 
 " values ("
```

Check any such discrepancies in the query, print it before executing, then try the query in pgadmin to see if there are any other issues.

Other reason may be the text values being inserted, with your code it may need the single quotes around each text value.

Please try using prepared statements, there won't be any overhead of complying  to these DB-native things.

Comment: I added a space but the problem persists, I have a similar .then function that uses the same syntax and everything, and the req.body object it pulls its data from is in a similar form. That function works, this one does however not, which I find pretty weird.

Comment: Ok, can you also try to include single quotes around the string values? Like this (add them around JSON.parse(id.id) if that's a text type too - `"INSERT INTO org (id, firstname, lastname, persid, role)" + 
 "values (" + JSON.parse(id.id) + ", '" + req.body.org.map((e: any) => e.firstname) + 
 "', '" + req.body.org.map((s: any) => s.lastname) + "', '" + req.body.org.map((x: any) 
 => x.persid) + "', '" + req.body.org.map((y: any) => y.role) + "') RETURNING id"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the trick for me! Do you know why it worked for me in previous .then tasks without the single quotes? I'm really interested in knowing why it suddenly did not work anymore without them!

Thanks a lot again!
Br,
Victor

Comment: Previous tasks may have queries which insert non-text columns, that's the best guess! But, apart from this solution, you should ideally use prepared statements, where the variable substitution easy and doesn't need these overheads like including single quotes. I have edited the answer in case someone else stumbles upon this issue.